# Will iPads with non-M1 chip be able to run iOS apps written for M1 chip in the future?

Tags: ios, ipad, hardware, apple-silicon

In the news I see that software written for macOS and Intel-based CPU should be optimized to run on M1 chip. I have also already seen some apps for macOS which only run on M1 chips.

I want to buy an iPad and it seems the entry level iPad has a non-M1 chip while more expensive ones such as the current generation iPad Air and iPad Pro has M1 chip.

Should apps written for non-M1 chip based iPad be optimized for M1 chip based iPads? In other words, the fragmentation we see in the macOS over its CPU will lead to developers to update and develop their software for M1 chip only. Will we see the same trend for iPads? Will an iPad with non-M1 chip receive iOS updates as long as its predecessors?

Comment: I’m not sure of the premise here. iPads have only ever been Apple Silicon. More important is to pick one of your three questions, though so we can try and focus on answering or closing as speculation each of the three questions asked

Comment: “Will we see the same trend for iPads?” Isn’t a good fit for this site as it’s speculative  / highly opinionated.

Comment: Same for most questions about what “developers” will do - that sort of thing works out in hindsight for a practical Q&A site. If this can be edited to ask “what did apple do” perhaps there an answer to be hosted / voted on.

Comment: @bmike that appears to us to be opinion but I think the OP is a few steps behind and needs to have explained that iPad ARM->M1 is not the same as Intel->ARM and so can be answered

Comment: I’m not sure that’s their question as the title is crystal clear, but editing the question to make it much more narrow is the first step. Sadly there is no research shown, just “people are saying”. Listing which apps, which news helps greatly

Comment: There are so many wrong assumptions here. You can't 'write for M1 only'. M1 is the same sort of processor as an A15: they are both Apple ARM chips, with the same instruction set. It's possible that a new OS might cut-off pre-M1 chips, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ipad and mac computers are totally different things.

pre M1 iPads still run an ARM cpu. The M1 is just a better version of existing iPad CPUs.

The issue of changing from Intel to ARM (Apple Silicon/M1) does not exist for devices running formas of iOS.

So updates in iPadOS will just follow normal Apple ways. At some date the newest version of iPadOS will not run on an old iPad.  I suspect the entry level iPad having the earlier ARM cpu will not upgrade to the latest iPadOS one version before the M1 iPads.